# Installation date and virtual status of the machine( For Darwin, FreeBSD and NetBSD)

Tags: terminal, freebsd, netbsd, darwin

How do I determine installation date (when the system was first booted) for Linux,Darwin, FreeBSD and NetBSD?  Also, Is there any way to get the virtual status of the these machines (whether the system is virtual or physical).  I need output using terminal commands.

For example,

Windows machine Installation date can be found using below command:

> Command:
>
> ```
> ssh host systeminfo | grep -i original
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> Original Install Date:     1/24/2014, 12:30:41 PM
> ```

Windows machine Virtual status of the machine can be found using below command:

> Command:
>
> ```
> ssh host systeminfo | grep -i manufacturer
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
> System Manufacturer:       VMware, Inc.
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On RedHat based Linux versions, timestamp of `/root/anaconda-ks.cfg` is a pretty good guide.  Or use `rpm -q --queryformat  '%{installtime:date}' basesystem`.

```
ls -l /root/anaconda-ks.cfg
-rw-------. 1 root root 2911 Nov 15  2014 /root/anaconda-ks.cfg

rpm -q --queryformat  '%{installtime:date}' basesystem
Sat 15 Nov 2014 08:40:28 AM PST
```

As for whether virtual or physical, reviewing contents of `/proc/scsi/scsi` is a fairly good guide.

```
cat /proc/scsi/scsi
Attached devices:
Host: scsi2 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: VMware,  Model: VMware Virtual S Rev: 1.0
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 02
```

As is `dmidecode -t 1`.

```
dmidecode -t 1 | grep Manufacturer
        Manufacturer: VMware, Inc.
```

Comment: `dmidecode` will also work in BSD systems.